# Change View size to match content

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have a class Token which extends View. I override the onDraw method to draw two rects. After that i want to change the size of the Token object to match the size of the rects. For testing i added an onClickListener which should print out "Test"

```
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    Token a = new Token(0,0, Token.ONE, p, this);
    layout.addView(a);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    });
```

The Token class:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    tSize = canvas.getWidth()/Activity.SIZE;
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    r.set(0, 0, tSize, tSize);
    canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
    r.set(tSize, 0, 2 * tSize, tSize);
    canvas.drawRect(r, paint);
    
}
```

So far so good. The problem is that it is always printing out "Test", no matter where i press on the screen. I figured that is because the View, which holds this two rects is the the size of the whole screen.
So i tried LayoutParams:

```
setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(tSize*2, tSize);
```

This results in the rects not showing up at all(i think they got to small). I tried some other numbers:

```
setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(600, 600);
```

This is working. The rects show up and the Listener only works in a 600x600 field. The only Problem is the rects are smaller than i want them to be. My guess is that their size is relative to the size of the view they are in.

How would i achive that my View is exactly (tSize*2, tSize) with the rects filling it out?

Answer (score 1):

you may override `onMeasure` method to change the GameTokenView's size.

Comment: use `setMeasuredDimension (width, height)` in  `onMeasure `

Comment: Generally speaking if you want change GameTokenView's size.you just override onMeasure , setLayoutParams only control your childview's space,onMeasure control your view's size